# PJSIP Video call

Tags: ios, video, pjsip

I have built the libraries for video support and it shows 2 codec found h263 and h264.

But when I run ipjsua video steaming is not happening, I have tried enabling video, enabling autorx and autotx but no positive results.

also when I list the windows it shows 0 windows found.
Please explain the steps to  capture and transmit video between devices
it would be a great help for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PJSIP wiki](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone) says:

> Note: video (from 2.x) is not yet supported on iOS.

And the [user´s guide](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Video_Users_Guide) says:

> Video is available on PJSIP version 2.0 and later. Only desktop platforms are supported, mobile devices such as iOS are not yet supported. This document describes how to use the video feature with PJSIP.

Comment: But some are able to build video library using third party codec like ffmpeg and they are successfully able to make viedo call. one of the link http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.voip.pjsip/16213